# How to delete Certain Characters in a excel 2013 cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of names in a column "A" having "Dr.", "Prof." as prefix. I need to remove these prefixes and retain only names.

`**Column A**        **Required only names in column B**
Prof.Dr.med.nameX
Dr.med.nameXX 
Prof. name XXX
Dr. XX
Pr.XX`

Comment: I have a list of those prefixes that needs to be removed form the column

Comment: How does the list of prefixes look like? Will you have an entry "Prof.Dr.med." or "Prof." and "Dr." and "med." as separate entries?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Can you show an image of the data?

Comment: How long is your list?

Answer (score 2):

Say we have a list of names in column **A**.  First we list the unwanted junk in column **C** and in **B1** we enter:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,INDEX($C$1:$C$6,SUMPRODUCT(ROW($C$1:$C$6)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1:$C$6,A1)))),""))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Derived from [Mike H. answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/formula-to-replace-junk-sub-strings/9030c539-acaa-43d5-8801-78073d6d9b37?auth=1)

Comment: This will only work if you have only one word of your junk list appearing. If you have for example "Prof. Dr. Jones" and you want to remove "Prof." and "Dr.", it will give you unexpected results.

Comment: @NiH **You are correct!**, its advantage is that it can handle a large "junk list"

Comment: Agreed. And it's deffinitely faster than a UDF. So the best solution will depend on the exact needs of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))
```

Not tested!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a very short and fixed-length list of substrings that you want to remove, you could do something like:

```
= TRIM( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( C1, $A$1, "" ), $A$2, "" ), $A$3; "" ), $A$4, "" ), $A$5, "" ) )
```

(with your original string in C1 and the range of substringsto be removed in A1:A5) .This is a bit messy though and not quite flexible. If you have no objections to using vba, I would propose to write a UDF similar to this:

```
Function UDF_MultiSubstitute(text As String, old_text_rng As Range, newText As String)

    Dim curCell As Range

    For Each curCell In old_text_rng
        text = Replace(text, curCell.Value, newText)
    Next

    UDF_MultiSubstitute = Trim(text)

End Function
```

which you can then invoke as:

```
= UDF_MultiSubstitute( C1, $A$1:$A$5, "" )
```

Obviuosly, you might want to add some error trapping etc. to the vba code

Comment: Your *UDF* approach is a lot more flexible.